# How to use createStackNavigator to create different home screens based on Authentication?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, stack-navigator

I am using React Native, and I want the user to be brought to a different home screen based on authentication. I am using Firebase as a database to determine whether the user is an admin or a normal user. How do I send the user to a different home screen based on the email they submit?

Here is my App.js code:

```
//downloaded libraries that allow different commands and tools
import React from 'react';
import {createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, Button, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoadingScreen from './screens/LoadingScreen';
import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './screens/LoginScreen';
import SurveyScreen from './screens/SurveyScreen';
import DetailsScreen from './screens/DetailsScreen'
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

//variable storing firebase api, authentication, and database keys
var firebaseConfig = {
    // excluded this part
};

//initializes firebase domain
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//navigation stacks for navigating between different screens
//one for user login (AuthStack) and the other for user screens (AppStack)
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    screen: Other
  },
  Survey: SurveyScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen
})

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  }
})

//exports navigation stacks to allow users to log in and navigate to different screens
//LoadingScreen.js is the first screen to load when app is initialized (initialRouteName: "Loading")
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Loading"
    }
  )
)
//navigation stacks for navigating between different screens
//one for user login (AuthStack) and the other for user screens (AppStack)
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    screen: Other
  },
  Survey: SurveyScreen,
  Details: DetailsScreen
})

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: {
    screen: LoginScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    },
  }
})

//exports navigation stacks to allow users to log in and navigate to different screens
//LoadingScreen.js is the first screen to load when app is initialized (initialRouteName: "Loading")
export default createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      Loading: LoadingScreen,
      App: AppStack,
      Auth: AuthStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: "Loading"
    }
  )
)
```

and here is my LoginScreen.js code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Image, KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

export default class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
    //default states of values "email", "password", and "errorMessage"
    state = {
        email: "",
        password: "",
        errorMessage: null
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        console.disableYellowBox = true;
    }

    //function that logs user in and redirects them to the first screen in AppStack (HomeScreen.js)
    //if the correct email and password credentials are met. if credentials are not met, an error
    //message will be displayed
    handleLogin = () => {
        const {email, password} = this.state
        firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}));
    };

    render() {
        //UI is coded in the return() area
        return (
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>
                <Image style={styles.image}
                source={require('../assets/EMSlogo.png')}></Image>

                <View style={styles.errorMessage}>
                    {this.state.errorMessage && <Text style={styles.error}>{this.state.errorMessage}</Text>}
                </View>

                <View style={styles.form}>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Email Address</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={email => this.setState({ email })}
                        value={this.state.email}></TextInput>
                    </View>

                    <View style={{marginTop: 32}}>
                        <Text style={styles.inputTitle}>Password</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.input} secureTextEntry autoCapitalize="none"
                        onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
                        value={this.state.password}></TextInput>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={this.handleLogin}>
                    <Text style={{color: "#FFF", fontWeight: "500", fontSize: 21}}>
                        Sign In
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
        )
    }
}

//this is how you create a stylesheet in react native
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    image: {
        margin: 30,
        marginBottom: 0,
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
    greeting: {
        marginTop: 32,
        fontSize: 18,
        fontWeight: "400",
        textAlign: "center"
    },
    errorMessage: {
        height: 72,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
        marginHorizontal: 30
    },
    error: {
        color: "#E9446A",
        fontSize: 16,
        fontWeight: "600",
        textAlign: "center"
    },
    form: {
        marginBottom: 48,
        marginHorizontal: 30,
    },
    inputTitle: {
        color: "#8A8F9E",
        fontSize: 16,
        textTransform: "uppercase"
    },
    input: {
        borderBottomColor: "#8A8F9E",
        borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
        height: 40,
        fontSize: 18,
        color: "#161F3D"
    },
    button: {
        marginHorizontal: 30,
        marginBottom: 35,
        backgroundColor: "#00235D",
        borderRadius: 4,
        height: 52,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After login navigate to your HomeScreen component and use conditional rendering based on the user type. in your handleLogin check user type and navigate to home screen, passing  user type as a param.

```
handleLogin = () => {
  const { email, password } = this.state;
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(() => {
      // check user type 
      // pass user type as param to home screen
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', { userType: 'admin or nomral user' });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
};
```

In your HomeScreen get user type, using `const userType = this.props.navigation.getParam('userType', '');`

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render = () => {
    const userType = this.props.navigation.getParam('userType', '');
    return (
      <View>
        {typeof userType === 'string' && userType.toLowerCase() === 'admin' ? (
          <Admin />
        ) : (
          <User />
        )}
      </View>
    );
  };
}
```

[DEMO](https://snack.expo.io/@lekgwaraj/admin-area-react-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a high order component that shows a login screen if user is not authenticated, otherwise show the admin page or the base page based on component props, for example:

HOC component

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Login from '../templates/login';

const AdminHOC = (props, Comp) => (WrappedComponent) => {
  return class LoaderHOC extends Component {
    render() {
      const { common: { user } } = this.props;
      const DefaultComponent = user ? Comp : Login;
      let valid = false;
      props.map((prop) => {
        if (user && user[prop]) {
          valid = true;
        }
        return true;
      });
      return valid
        ? (
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        )
        : (
          <DefaultComponent {...this.props} />
        );
    }
  };
};


export default AdminHOC;
```

Then in your admin page component:

```js
class Admin extends Component {
...
}

class Home extends Component {
...
}

// admin and development are props that needs to be true to render the admin page
// If both are false it shows a regular home page
export default AdminHOC(['admin', 'development'], Home)(Admin);
```

In this way you can wrap any component that needs a user to be admin and show other component if not.